# Does Make expand recursive-variables before exporting them?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***Given a Makefile:***

```make
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"


0 ::
    @$(MAKE)


else


1 ::
    @echo 'foo is: "$(foo)"'


endif
```

***And executing, we get:***

```console
$ make foo='$@'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
foo is: "1"
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'


$ make foo='$@' --environment-overrides
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
foo is: "0"
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

So we have here a *recursive* variable `foo` with the value: `$@`, which - of course - expands to the name of the *target*. Now, we have two options here:

1. Either, Make expands ***first*** the variable, and then export the variable to a sub-make.


    With this "logic", when Make runs the first makefile (`MAKELEVEL = 0`), it will build the *target* ***0***, Hence: expand the variable `foo`(and its value:`$@`) to `0`, and then export - this already expanded value - to the sub-make.
    
    
    This result, with the sub-make running its makefile, with a variable `foo` that has the simple value: `0`.


   This is in-fact the case, when we run `make --environment-overrides`, as you can see in the second run of the makefile, in the example above.
2. Another "logic" is, for Make to pass the value "verbatim". That means, with no expansion!

   Hence all recursive variables will be still intact, when passed to the second Make.


   For this logic, **only** the sub-make is allowed to expand its variables recursively, hence: any recursive-expansion will be done in the context of the sub-make.


   In our example above, that we had `foo` with its value `$@`, if we are to follow this logic, Make will pass the value `$@` "verbatim", with no expansion at all, so the sub-make will effectively see a value `$@` for its `foo` variable, hence: when expanding in the context of ***its*** target, that happens to be ***1***, it will recursively expand `foo`(and its value: `$@`) to ***1***.


   Actually, this is the "normal" behaviour that is evident in the first run of makefile, as evident in the example above.

So, for a lack of clear methodology, we are left to conclude, that this behaviour of either ***expand and then export*** or ***export and then expand*** is inconsistent.

That is, sometimes Make will choose the first method, where sometimes it will chose the second.

In our example, it was a command-line option (`--environment--overrides`), that acted as a deciding factor, as to what method Make has to choose.

But, can we really justify, that these - seemingly - **unrelated** features (i.e export/recursive vs. environment-overrides), will end up to have such a dramatic effect on each-other?

***(Versions note: 4.0 and up).***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` does export foo in expanded form, as can be seen here:

```
target:
    @echo "'$$foo'"
```

Output:

```
$make foo='$@'
'target'
```

However, to pass its argument to sub-makes, it does not use the environment directly -- instead it stuffs everything into the variable `MAKEFLAGS`.  And there it passes foo unexpanded:

```
target:
    @echo "'$$MAKEFLAGS'"
```

Output:

```
$make foo='$@'
' -- foo=$$@'
```

To be clear: the sub-make does import `foo` from the environment, but that is then overridden by the setting from `MAKEFLAGS`.

When you specify `--environment--overrides`, that means that environment variables take precedence over settings in the makefile.  The GNU make documentation does not explicitly specify what happens to variables passed in via `MAKEFLAGS` in the presence of `--environment--overrides`, but apparently they are overridden too.

Comment: Very **good** points. Thanks. We still have to address the ***how*** and ***why***. That is, ***how*** - did it happen - that exporting of *command-line* variables get affected by a command-line *option* such as `--environment-overrides`. But - more troubling, is the ***why***. i.e. Why would exporting of a variable that was defined on the *command-line*, and **only** on the command-line, be allowed to be affected by an - seemingly - unrelated command-line options, such as `--environment-overrides`.

Comment: Because, semantically speaking, it is **always** (i.e. no matter, if you used `--environment-overrides` or not) a command-line - level - variable (which is, of course, a level higher from a environment-level variable, even with `--environment-overrides`). So, exporting-wize, Make should always use the same (or equivalent) mechanism to do the ***same*** sort of export (i.e. either expand first, or not. ***always***).